# Is there any reason not to straight up delete question and re-ask it if it gets put on "hold"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, moderation, on-hold

If I make a question and mess up (*or perhaps an overly zealous moderators step in*) and the question gets put on HOLD, is there any reason not to straight up delete the question and re-ask it?

Reopening the question takes 5 votes and it seems like very unlikely to get reopened anytime soon or at all.

Comment: Why not? Because you would get question banned very soon.

Comment: @Rizier123 even if it happens rarely?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean with rarely?

Comment: Isn't it reasonable to just expect to re-ask the question if the question would never  be able leave the on HOLD status even after you edited it?

Comment: The purpose of re-asking is not to *bump* the question. Rather get rid of the on HOLD status which might appear to be unrealistic to be removed since it takes 5 votes to reopen it and I don't see any motivation for anyone to vote to reopen it UNLESS it's a super HOT question.

Comment: No. First you have all the time to ask the question first. And you have many links everywhere to help pages. Then if you edit your closed question it goes into the reopen queue, so if you made a good edit it will get reopened.

Comment: No, it's not reasonable. In fact, you're likely going to attract downvotes from anyone who saw both questions, and you may hear from a moderator. The correct way to handle a question being closed is to edit the question, vote to reopen, etc. It is _not_ to delete/reask your question. There's an entire review queue for reopening closed questions, so your assumption that reopening is unlikely isn't necessarily correct.

Comment: @JBeurer It also takes 5 people to close. And just because you re-ask the question doesn't make it better it will get closed again and the user will get question banned over time.

Comment: I have a feeling there's the *virtual rewards* in place for voting to close. Or just some people liking to *play police*. Is there any *incentives* / rewards for voting to open and voting to close?

Comment: It is not reasonable to be deleting and putting back up a question, the HOLD status mainly gets put there on purpose. If you do a major edit that makes it reasonable, it will be put back anyway.

Comment: @JBeurer the reward is keeping the quality of the site to the standards that made it the best QA site...

Comment: Also it seems highly unlikely that anyone who saw the original question (like tens of people) would down-vote the newly opened one.

Comment: @Patrice, I wish the world worked like that. I'd argue that *virtual rewards* is one of the key reasons for it's success.

Comment: @JBeurer no you're right, I wouldn't downvote if I saw something like that "reappear"... I'd get curious, dig in, check who posted what, and potentially flagging for moderator attention....

Comment: @JBeurer what are you trying to hint at? "My question got wrongly put on hold"? (I guess). Without a question to check, no one will tell you that. Link the question, maybe? (OH just clicked, you meant that rep is all that made Stack what it is... riiiiight, because experts known around the world like Jon Skeet come here for the pretty rep he gets, not because he can FINALLY answer good questions because a site has some frakking standard instead of accepting code dumps...)

Comment: @Patrice, I didn't say that it's wrongly put on hold. It could get put on HOLD for any reason. Lets say it was NOT a well written question. And it needed some modifications. Now, that I have edited the question it appears to me that it wont get reopened simply because I dont see 5 people somehow stumbling upon it and reopening it in any reasonable timeframe.

Comment: @JBeurer There is a queue your question will go into.

Comment: I also don't see why simply not leave a comment on the question if a person is not clear about what's being asked instead of straight up freezing it. Or give some time before it gets put on HOLD. Enough time to fix it.

Comment: @JBeurer but there's no "stumbling".... 1) when you edit, the question gets bumped to the top of the "active question" list. Which is something some people DO monitor... 2) the reopen queue routinely goes to 0 questions, which mean people WILL see your new version. 3) reasonable timeframe? Since when is that a concern on here?

Comment: "Also it seems highly unlikely that anyone who saw the original question (like tens of people) would down-vote the newly opened one." - Wrong, when I see someone re-ask a question because it got closed, I insta-dupe close it. If it's delete+re-ask, I'll drop a comment to crowd-source others to "destroy" the new question. Because to put it simply, reasking to get around closure is a huge abuse of the system.

Comment: @JBeurer but hold is the "time to fix" before we delete it. It's EXACTLY how you want it to work. Hold is just a "mmmm... please fix this, your question does look okay, it's not unsalvageable. Edit it to the quality standards of the site and someone will reopen"

Comment: @Patrice, but most questions get so few views that it's highly unlikely that 5 people would go out of their way to vote to reopen it. Would take unreasonable amount of time. That's how I see it.

Comment: @JBeurer As has been said a few times now, when you edit your question, it is added to a review queue.  Eg, people don't just _stumble_ upon it, its shoved in their faces in a way(should they choose to click the review link in the menu bar that they gain access to at a certain rep threshold).  As to your _virtual rewards_ argument.  There are none for closing questions.  We don't get rep for it, nor do we get badges for it.

Comment: @Daedalus that at least clears it up.

Comment: @JBeurer but again "unreasonable".... we don't really mind the timeframe on stack. So if you ask today, it gets reopened in a week and answered in a month, meh. The intent is for every new visitor with the same question to get their solution. Anyway, agaion, no one "goes out of their way" to reopen. People routinely go and empty the reopen queue (I try to sit down for a half hour of queue work a day. I know some people do WAY more).... so there's no stumbling.

Comment: @Patrice, yeah, if a person has to wait a week to be able to get the question removed from on hold status, he will find a way to ask the question. Ban won't stop him. I don't think the attitude is conductive to improving the system.

Comment: @JBeurer And your attitude of "if I don't like a rule I'll bend it to get my answer" is? Seriously man... there are guidelines to how to work with the site, and it's best to just go with them.  (and... which attitude, if I may ask? I really don't get what you're hinting at there)

Comment: @JBeurer but again, you focus on the timeframe. Lemme ask you a question : what do you think the goal of stack is? (honestly, this is the KEY difference most new users miss, and it explains a lot of the processes/way the site works)

Comment: It's about being pragmatic. Rule is only useful if it's helpful. I question the helpfulness of the way on hold system is implemented at the moment.

Comment: @JBeurer It certainly won't "stop" anyone dedicated enough. But the site has some pretty good spam detection algorithms for slowing down trolls like that.

Comment: @JBeurer the rule IS helpful for the goal of the site. Seriously, answer me: what do you think the endgoal of the site is?

Comment: To be honest, even if you get it reopened, there is no incentive for those that originally down-voted to revisit your question and remove the negative votes, even if you rewrote the question entirely into something they would probably up-vote the second time around. Reposting the same content will get you banned, but if you delete then rewrite the question entirely (from a different perspective for instance), I don't see why you'd get in trouble.

Comment: @MeirionHughes you assume it's downvoted. It's not. It has one vote and one favorite. It was put on hold so fast before I could react.

Comment: @Jbeurer btw i'm not trying to be a dick with my question. Usually there is a very different point of view when people first join the site. Once they realize what stack is meant to be, the rules make sense. It's a BIG difference in seeing quality and processes. That said, not sure you necessarily want to conti ue that convo. If you do, feel free to ping me, I'll try to explain (i have some time on my hand for that today^^)

Comment: @Patrice, I've used the site for years. The moderation has gotten overly eager over time. I don't know what incentives there are for it. Perhaps some people just like *playing the role* waaay too much.

Comment: @Patrice I think the question about the goal of the site is multi-faceted, depending on who you ask. I assume you are asking for the *official mission* statement.

Comment: @Jbeurer not necessarily official. More the intent, the mindset, the reasoning. The thing that made stack what it is, basically.

Comment: Oh and i agree moderation got more aggressive..... Where you see it as over zealousness... I see it as a scalability problem where we are drowning in garbage Qs.

Answer (score 9):

There's two ***very big*** reasons why you don't want to do this.

1. The negatively scored and closed question **counts against you for a potential question ban.** You want to improve that question as much as you possibly can.
2. If you ask a similar question, **it is eligible to be closed as a duplicate** of your earlier question, even if **it has no answers**.

Both of these reasons motivate one thing:  you must improve your existing question.  I can appreciate that it takes a while to get things reopened, but it *does* happen.  We have reopen queues which will drop your question in after it's been edited for more people to gain exposure to it, so that it stands a better chance of being reopened.

Do your part in editing your question to address the reason why it was closed as best as you can.

Comment: Thank you! I mean, the original question would get deleted first. So duplication thing would not happen I think.

Comment: @JBeurer:  Even if it's deleted, at a bare minimum it still counts against you in the possible question ban scenario.  So I would strongly discourage it.

Comment: Actually the linked question - Can self-censoring end up with a question ban? - which *supposedly*  is similar - has an answer which says that question bans are not handed out for deleting questions without answers.

Comment: @JBeurer:  If it's downvoted it still counts.  If it's closed it still counts.  Deletion by itself doesn't factor in, but if either of those other conditions apply, it would count.

Comment: it's not downvoted, it's not closed. It's just put on hold.

Comment: @JBeurer:  You're in an ideal (and rare) position then.  You should edit it now while you have the chance to and improve the question.

Comment: I did edit the question, now I have to wait - what I assume is - a long time - before it gets reopened. This is why I was considering the course of action and was wondering how and why this backwards (imho) system is put in place

Comment: @JBeurer:  First:  don't assume.  It may take a while, it may not.  Second:  be patient.  Things take time.

Comment: @JBeurer "it's not closed. It's just put on hold" The two are the same thing.  Closed questions are just labeled "on hold" in an attempt to get people to edit them, as they are supposed to do.  Anything that applies to a "closed" question applies to an "on hold question, because an "on hold" question *is closed*.

Comment: Why is it backwards? You are not supposed to send half assed questions to the site. Your question isn't q draft you correct. It's a final version that's supposedly good enough for every single future visitor. If you don't do that, you have to go through the process. The process does involve waiting. You made a boo boo, you pay for it. For me it's anything but backwards. (and stop assuming it HAS to get reopened today.... You have an assignment/project/deliverable to meet?)

Comment: @Patrice, 1) it incentivizes to delete the question and re-ask it. Not only is it easier, it takes way less time and is simple. Moreover there's absolutely no harm done in doing so 2) it's brutish when a question gets abruptly closed with vague "as unclear" without any explanation or time to provide it. It's abrupt and makes stackoverflow seem hostile and unfriendly. Comments seem to work very well when a person needs a clarification. Moreover according to the *duplicate question* answer deleting a question and re-asking doesn't appear to be bannable. If it is, so be it. I'll work around this.

Comment: Especially if the question isn't down-voted or inappropriate and has no answers and has like 10-20 views, 5 of which were moderators who closed it. Nice!

Comment: @Jbeurer 1) do that enough with bad content, and if the question was on hold when you delete it, it'll have bad consequences eventually.. 2) some could argue posting a question without polishing it enough for it to be on par with the site's quality is actually ruder. I 100% agree comments help in clarifying. I 100% agree Stack may seem arid and harsh at times. I also 100% think that there is no better Q&A site around. That got to be the fact because of the focus on quality.

Comment: Look, at the end of the day, you don't want to discuss this. You just want your way,because you're not even open to seeing ANY OTHER WAY. Multiple times you complained about time and people mentioned the reopen queue (which i see DAILY at 0. if it gets emptied daily,then your questio. Should get reopened before a day if it's worth reopening.). Seriously, there is a justificatoon for this rule, and wheneber anyone tries to elude to it all you say is "I'll find a way around it". You just don't respect the site or its goals (which you STILL havent commented on), and want your answer NOW.

Comment: That, if you ask me, is way more toxic to the site than any pther behavior could be. Anyway if you are willing to discuss and see WHY this was made like that, why the site got this way,I'll be happy to. Keep stomping your feet and disregarding this community... Then complain that it's too harsh. Start by respecting it, it may respect you. If you sincerely wanna talk, hit me up I'll junp in a chatroom. If not, then just delete your question and repost it. Not much i can do to stop you. I can just tell you that using stack PROPERLY is defi itely more useful than acting like an entitled kid

Comment: @Patrice, why all the ad hominems, please provide a single valid argument (or counter-argument) why *any other way* is better instead of getting all emotional. This very question here on this site is asking for it. All I've gotten so far is "because rules" or "you're gonna get banned". It's not particularly wise to blindly follow rules, if the rules don't serve the user-base well (and if you can get away it).

Comment: @Jbeurer I'm not emotioal, quite the opposite actually. I'm just tired of people not wanting to listen and just stomping around. Three times I've told you "the end goal of the site is linked to all these rules and reqsons. Mind saying what you think it is?" (in so many words). You've never answered that. That makes it hard to move the convo forward, no? As patient and willing to help as i am, i don't want to lose my time,which is what seems to be happening there.

Comment: And i never said "because rules"i said "these rules have a link to the end goal of the site". I just wanted to make sure we agree on that goal to see how/what to explain and justify. Without your point of view, this is hard, neh?

Comment: And you say "serve the userbase". But we first need to agree on what is "serving the userbase". Anyway you seem to be under the impression delete + repost is an immunity. If your question is at 0 score and on hold when you delete it, it DEFINITELY will hit you on the question ban, because that is not a good reception. This alone should justify why it's a bad idea. Your answer to that was to shrug it off and say "what if it doesn't haooen often?" this is clear disregard for the community

Comment: If you don't feel like answering about the end goal of the site. Mind telling me why it's so urgent to have it reopened now and why it cannot wait? Again, the reopen queue hits 0 posts at least daily. You can't wait that?

Comment: @Patrice, Why are you so hell-bent on trying to prove that I disrespect the community, etc? My point of view here is irrelevant, all that matters are sound arguments and reason - so far none.

Comment: @Jbeurer blatant disregard for the rules of it seems like it(and if you disagree with the rules, you ipen a FR on meta to change them, you don't just disregard them) How often have you basically said "i will just work around it"? Come on. Anyway, you STILL haven't answered any of my questions, which i think i framed correctly in highlighting how the discussion will stem from this. I honestly have better things to do, if you won't even try to move this forward. Enough wasted time here.

Comment: @JBeurer: "*Why are you so hell-bent on trying to prove that I disrespect the community, etc?*" Because you suggested that it was OK to delete and re-ask a question that the *community* told you was *unacceptable*. Such an act is profoundly disrespectful to the community.

Comment: @NicolBolas it seems that you don't understa\nd the mindset and social mores of many SO question posters.  There is a set who are essentially sociopaths and dont care who else is incovenienced or insulted as long as they get their answer quickly.  They must get their answer, and nothing in the rules, or what is said on meta, will stop them.  Another set come from environments where cheating, lying and scamming is a normal way of life and, if someone does not want to be abused, it's up to them to avoid it.  Both these sets of SO users will cheat, lie and misrepresent to achieve their aim.

Comment: @MartinJames: I understand that. I just wanted to make it clear which side of that line he was promoting and why.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I made an honest question instead of straight up acting (which is what I should have done in the first place). In return this question got downvoted into oblivion, and all the first responses were of "you'll get banned" and "it's rules" nature. When I asked more questions of what are the upsides of the current system (or downsides to delete-re-asking), no arguments were provided. Instead *everyone* was focusing on attacking my character.

Comment: Nobody, even for a moment gave a thought or any consideration that - perhaps - there are some deficiencies in the way some questions get closed without providing any clear comments. (e.g. 5 people with enough rep can just straight up close question instantly without providing any info)

Comment: @NicolBolas, what does it achieve proving that I disrespect the community or pointing out some other flaws in my character? (lets assume I disrespect the community). What does it have to do with the arguments presented? And answering the question at hand? Is the objective to be able to dismiss every argument I present after *it's proven* that i'm X or Y? Why stray away from question at hand and dodge my arguments instead attack my character?